# sending headrs to web API from winForm client

Tags: c#, api, winforms, http-headers

i have a simple demo winform app and im trying to make a post request with header to web api.
i received access token and refreash token form the server and i stored that in text file.
and im trying to make a post request by sending the refreash token with the body and sending the access token with the header but i dont know how to include the header with the post request.

this my post method

```
public static async Task<string> sendMessage(string name, string contents)
        {
            

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //reading the access token and refreash token from file
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\noorm\Desktop\noor.txt");
                string accessToken, refreashToken;
                accessToken = sr.ReadLine();
                refreashToken = sr.ReadLine();

                //defining new instance of message opject
                var newMessage = new messages()
                {
                    name = name,
                    content = contents,
                    refreashToken = refreashToken

                };
               
                //sening the opject using post async and returning the response
                var newPostJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newMessage);
                var payLoad = new StringContent(newPostJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                
                    using (HttpResponseMessage res = await client.PostAsync(baseURL + "/messages", payLoad))
                    {
                        using (HttpContent content = res.Content)
                        {

                            string data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            if (data != null)
                            {
                                return data;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                
            }


            return string.Empty;
        }
```

and this is the button

```
private async void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var responce = await restHelper.sendMessage(txtName.Text.Trim(),txtContent.Text.Trim());
            rtxt.Text = responce;
        }
```

Comment: [HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(string, string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httpheaders.add?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#system-net-http-headers-httpheaders-add(system-string-system-string))

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "Your Oauth token");
```

Comment: thanks mr yenkay i have tried that before and it didnt work and my server expects a header name and token without bearer

Answer (score 0):

this is how i was able to send the access token with the header

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-auth-token", accessToken);
```